# Using Facts From Related Lawsuits

Tags: united-states, federal-courts

If a person defaults in a lawsuit the facts alleged in the complaint become true.  My question is can those uncontested facts now be used against the same party in a related lawsuit?

Answer (score 1):

The “facts” do not “become true”: they were and are untested assertions and therefore unproven “facts”. If they are challenged, the person who asserted the “facts” has the onus to prove they are, in fact, facts.

Comment: More technically, the doctrine of collateral estoppel (a.k.a. issue preclusion) generally does not apply to issues resolved in a case that are not resolved on the merits following a full and fair opportunity to litigate them.